# RxJava. Вызов onError после onNext

Tags: android, rxjava

Необходимо вызывать onNext и сразу после этого вызвать метод onError. Код:

```
    Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
            e.onNext("value");
            e.onError(new Exception("exc"));
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                    Log.v("TAG", s);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.v("TAG", throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });
```

В этом случае вызывается только метод onError. Но если поставить задержку в 500 миллисекунд - сначала вызовется onNext и затем уже onError. Кто-нибудь может подсказать почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: покажите второй вариант кода с задержкой

Comment: Между onError и onNext вставить Thread.sleep(500);

Comment: а что у вас за кейс, что надо сначала вызвать onNext а потом сразу onError?

Comment: в случае отсутствия соединения с интернетом - обрщащаюсь к локальному хранилищу и возвращаю закешированные данные + отображаю сообщение об ошибке, чтобы пользователь знал, что нет соединения.

Comment: Если используете связку Rx + Retrofit, onError() при отсутствии интернета вызовется сам. Если вам неоходимо обрабатывать несколько ошибок в onError(), залогируйте message ошибки при отсутствии интернета и добавьте в метод onError switch-case конструкцию, в которой определяете из-за чего вызвана ошибка. Можно также использовать свою реализацию класса Throwable для определения ошибки (В onError() потом используя instanceof).